# Scripting a Persona Login

Tags: authentication, web-scraping, persona

I want to try and scrape data from the Mozilla Marketplace so that I can have a daily email of downloads and installs that are reported there.

This is all fine and I have done this is many other place simulating HTTP Post for a "normal" login form.

However, can something similar be done with Persona via code to login programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

A few of the tools and work-arounds are mentioned in this thread: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/mozilla.dev.identity/BkvU9FJQ5Uw/discussion

Feel free to ask for more information there.